# How to use material-ui(-next) Select with async options

Tags: material-ui

I thought async options is very common use case for Select component, yet i haven't seen an example how it can be done with material-ui(-next) Select.

I'm not sure whether I should just add another dependency to "react-select" for its async options feature. But I would avoid this if it can be done just with material-ui Select

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the autocomplete component in material-ui:

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests